# How do I reinstall ubuntu from 32 bit to 64 bit?

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, 64-bit, grub-efi

---

### What I did to get in this mess

I'm a new ubuntu convert and tried dual booting my lenovo ideapad 100 with Ubuntu gnome and windows 10.
 Turns out i failed, I installed ubuntu in legacy mode because that was the only way the laptop would let me. I didn't delete my windows partitions but windows 10 can't boot now, I guess I will need to reinstall it in legacy mode (How do I do that? Being able to use my old partitions would be great too).

---

### Installing ubuntu from 32 bit to 64 bit

Another problem I have is that I installed the ubuntu GNOME 32 bit version, thinking I couldn't use the 64 bit version called AMD64, because i have an intel processor( Only later did I realize that i can, and should've installed that). So I looked around and found that I can somehow upgrade it in the terminal, but that reinstalling it completely is better and less hassle. This being an almost clean install I don't mind reinstalling, but how am I supposed to do that? ( + I've already flashed the needed 64 bit image on a USB)

---

### Additional

Here's my boot info if that helps:
http://paste2.org/A0ZX9f7m

Comment: You need to repair your Windows 10 first and then install Ubuntu 16.04 - 64 bit second. And I completely agree calling the Intel 64 bit code AMD64 was a huge mistake.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix The reason why it is called amd64 us because AMD introduced the 64bit processors and as such, at that time amd64 was used for 64bit OS. Although Intel also introduced 64bit processors after that, however naming 64bit OSes as amd64 became a convention. P.S. All distros do not follow this convention as some refer it as x86_64

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix So how can i fix my windows? Without loosing my windows files?

Comment: FYI my windows 10 consists of only one partition(everything is on ther, the system files, and my personal files). I didn't install it like that, that's just how I got it and didn't bother to change it

Answer (score 1):

Chances are your Windows installation is intact and bootable but is not booting because you've activated your firmware's Compatibility Support Module (CSM), aka "BIOS mode" or "legacy mode" support. If I'm right, de-activating the CSM should fix the Windows boot problem. Details of how to do this vary from one computer to another, so I can't provide step-by-step instructions.

If you can get Windows booting in EFI mode again, I suggest you try again to install *64-bit* Ubuntu in EFI mode. See [this page of mine](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/csm-good-bad-ugly.html) for background information on why using the CSM is bad. That page also includes [a section](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/csm-good-bad-ugly.html#creating-media) on creating EFI-bootable USB drives, which seems to be the single biggest hurdle people face when trying to install Ubuntu in EFI mode. Note that installing 64-bit Ubuntu in EFI mode will be a fresh installation, so your old 32-bit installation will be completely wiped out, including your user data. If you've stored files you want to keep, be sure to back them up to external media. Also, you may need to use the "Something Else" installation option, as described in [this question and its answers.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation) If you use one of the more automated settings, you may end up with both the old and the new installations living side-by-side, but the old one will likely be useless, or at least redundant.